# Weird error in sklearn.cluster.KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to use mr. yasaichi's implementation of x-means written in Python for my master's thesis (yasaichi's x-means: https://gist.github.com/yasaichi/254a060eff56a3b3b858) . For the last few weeks there have been no problem and I have been running the algorithm several times on various data sets. Today, however, a weird error popped up:

> AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'get_params'.

The error comes from line 75 in the yasaichi's implementation:

> labels = range(0, k_means.get_params()["n_clusters"])

Originally I thought it was me who had done some weird changes to the code, but when I re-downloaded the original again it came up with the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of asking us to fix someone elses code you found on the internet - **try to fix it yourself**. Maybe it was written for an older/newer/extended version of sklearns k-means, for example.

Comment: I have been using it for about two weeks now without problems. I fully believe (and know) the code works, which is what I find funny about it all. I only post the question here because I don't have the faintest of how to proceed now. I have not updated any packages on my OS (Ubuntu 12.04.5 precise penguin) and I run it in a VM with no network access.
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the KMeans object you are trying to use doesn't have the method `get_params`.

I just tested the code at https://gist.github.com/yasaichi/254a060eff56a3b3b858 and it worked for me. So, my best guess is that you are somehow overwriting the KMeans object or that your code is using a cached version of the code that defines the `KMeans` object.

To verify this, try adding `print dir(k_means)` before line 75 of yasaichi's implementation. You should also see that `print k_means.__module__` should show `sklearn.cluster.k_means_`. If this is the case, the final thing I would recommend would be deleting the compiled Python file implementing the `k_means_` module. This can be found by running the following:

```
import sklearn.cluster.k_means_
print sklearn.cluster.__file__
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion!

I just tested it out and it seems `get_params` is a part of my version of `KMeans`. Along with quite a few other not on your list, apparently!

Comment: Oops, I just re-read my first answer and realized that it was incorrect. I've provided a correction.